# Magento 1.x How to get customer paid amount in my custom module file?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How to get customer paid amount for the order? i want to validate the Order total amount and customer paid amount. can anyone please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**using This :-**

```
$order->getTotalPaid();
```

Comment: It gives order total amount.. I want to get customer paid amount

Comment: please attach screenshot which exactly you want total